# Starting a project through another project in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

My notepad program in vb is stored in C:\libraries\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\notepad\notepad\bin\debug\notepad.exe
And my Tic-Tac-Toe program is stored in C:\libraries\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tic-Tac-Toe\Tic-Tac-Toe\bin\debug\Tic-Tac-Toe.exe

These are the paths of the applications(the ones which will run when double clicked)

Now, I want to create a third project in visual basic. It will have only two buttons. One, to run tic-tac-toe and the other to run notepad. How do I achieve this? That is, how do I make one project run when I click a button on another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to call the `Process.Start` method and pass it the file path of the executable you want to launch.  There are other ways of doing it that provide more flexibility, but I imagine that's sufficient for what you need.  For instance:

```
Process.Start("C:\libraries\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\notepad\notepad\bin\debug\notepad.exe")
```

However, I would recommend putting the path in the app.config or some other configuration location because that path will likely change on other PC's.

Comment: It is giving me an unhandled exception that the file specified cannot be found although I have given the right path

Comment: Libraries is not a valid folder name.  It's a fake location that windows explorer displays and accepts, but it is not an actual physical folder in the file system.  Your actual path is probably something along the lines of `C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\notepad\notepad\bin\debug\notepad.exe`.  To get the true path, right-click on the executable in the explorer, select the "Properties" option from the context menu, open the "General" tab in the properties dialog window, and look at the "Location:" line.

Comment: It works when I only put notepad.exe, but not when I mention the whole path.

Comment: When you don't specify the path, it assumes the current directory.